# Sketchflow builds but does not show in IE

Tags: silverlight, sketchflow

I have a sketchflow application that was building fine. I ran it again and viewed it in IE. It shows the silverlight loading logo which disapears.

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That usually means there is an exception being thrown in your app. There will sometimes be a yellow warning icon in the status bar that can show what happened. Otherwise you can open and run the app in VS to find out what the exception is.